# echo to file - error: cannot create

Tags: unix, echo, ksh

In Unix ksh. I am trying to create a text file with few lines of text in it using below echo statement

```
echo $multilinetext > ../in/log_file
```

The error i am getting is "Cannot Create". Also this code worked fine before some time.

Through filezilla i am able to create the file. The "in" directory has all permissions(777).
the Dir hierarchy is as below

```
ParentDir
     in
     Bin
         test.ksh
```

test.ksh is executing the echo command

What else should be causing the error

**Update:
The problem was that i executed the script from parentDir. So instead of saying the file does not exist, it found the test.ksh file in Bin and executed it without any errors. which caused it to look for "in" directory in wrong location**

Is it possible to check if the script is executed from its own directory?

Comment: Could this depend on the particular text?  Your symbol is "multilinetext" implying it has multiple lines in it.  If it does, do you need `echo "$multilinetext" > ../in/log_file`?  Do you have enough free space on the disk?  Is the FS still R/W or has errors and is now R/O?

Comment: I could fix the error. the error was because i was trying to execute test.ksh from ParentDir. So instead of saying the file does not exist. it simply executed the file from Bin directory. I counter checked it again. that s what exactly it does.

Comment: If it were my script, I'd be adding a check for this condition, so I could print a nice informative message.  Six months from now, you'll forget about this and reasking the question :-)

Comment: Totally new to the environment :(  How can i add this condition ? Is it a normal behavior in unix? is it checking in each sub directory for the file ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your full script?  Or at least enough of it surrounding this.  I'd be glad to post an answer, but I don't want to create something out-of-context that looks totally alien to you.

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your request, here's a small script based on what you've posted about your hierarchy:

```
#!/bin/sh -

# adjust this to suit
bin_dir="/tmp/top/bin"
multi=`cat /etc/passwd`

# get current directory
pwd="`pwd`"

# check to ensure we're in the correct directory
if [ "$pwd" != "$bin_dir" ]; then
    echo "not executing from correct bin directory"
    exit
fi

target_dir="../in"

# ensure the target directory for writing exists
if [ -d "$target_dir" ]; then
    echo $multi > $target_dir/log_file
else
    echo "unable to locate directory '$target_dir' -- does not exist"
fi
```